# RabbitMQ failing inexplicably, restart required, restart fixes problem

Tags: rabbitmq

RabbitMQ keeps failing and we fix it by restarting the service but we don't know why it fails.  Has anybody else experienced these issues?

Answer (score 0):

A better place to ask this question is the [RabbitMQ discuss](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rabbitmq-discuss) mailing list.  The devs hang around there and make a point of answering every question posted.

Also, your question gives very little information.  A more detailed description would be useful; posting the log file would also help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue in Rabbitmq 2.2.0 that could cause these symptoms.

You should downgrade to 2.1.1 until the next version of RabbitMQ is released.